# Refresh Token Lifespan (Microsoft Graph)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was trying to find out how long the refresh_token lasts, but the only meaningful resource I was able to find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101568/microsoft-graph-api-refresh-token-expired) stackoverflow thread from August 2017, where it says that the max lifespan is 14 days, but that things may have changed and it (may) remain valid forever now.

So, right now, is there an expiry date for the refresh_token? And if so, what would the procedure be from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That thread points at the Azure AD documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes). Azure AD is the authority that issues your tokens for Microsoft Graph.

From that doc, there are some key takeaways:

- There are default lifetimes but these are configurable.
- The defaults are based on how the token is obtained. Values are different between a user that uses multi-factor auth vs. a user that doesn't, for example.
- Refresh tokens can be revoked by the user at any time.

Based on that information, apps should not take a dependency on a set refresh token lifetime.

For all the defaults, see the table at https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-token-lifetime-properties